# MySQL query to fetch data using date range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, daterangepicker

This query is giving correct result in MySql workbench -

```
SELECT tbl_visit_info.visitor_id,tbl_visit_info.retailer_id,tbl_retailer.retailer_shop_name,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 1 ,1,0)) AS feedback,
SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 2 ,1,0)) AS promise_order,
SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 3 ,1,0)) AS stock,
SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 6 ,1,0)) AS payment,
tbl_visit_info.date as visit_date
FROM tbl_visit_info,tbl_retailer 
where tbl_visit_info.retailer_id=tbl_retailer.retailer_id 
and tbl_visit_info.visitor_id=80
group by visitor_id,retailer_id 
having date_format(tbl_visit_info.date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-09-02';
```

But, when I want to pass variables in place of 80 and date range as a variable then it is not giving any result. Query is-

```
SELECT tbl_visit_info.visitor_id,tbl_visit_info.retailer_id,tbl_retailer.retailer_shop_name,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 1 ,1,0)) AS feedback,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 2 ,1,0)) AS promise_order,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 3 ,1,0)) AS stock,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 6 ,1,0)) AS payment
  FROM tbl_visit_info,tbl_retailer
  where tbl_visit_info.retailer_id=tbl_retailer.retailer_id
  and tbl_visit_info.visitor_id='".$_GET["sr_id"]."'
  group by visitor_id,retailer_id having date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 
  '".$_GET["start_date"]."' AND '".$_GET["end_date"]."'"
```

This query is not giving any result when I am writing code in PHP.

Comment: What format are `$_GET["start_date"]` and `$_GET["end_date"]` in

Comment: can you please tell us your $_GET["start_date"] and $_GET["end_date"] and $_GET["sr_id "] values ?

Comment: Please do not create SQL queries by joining strings together. You should always use parametrised queries, otherwise you have a significant security risk from SQL injection.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should date filter in where clause instead of using having:

```
SELECT tbl_visit_info.visitor_id,tbl_visit_info.retailer_id,tbl_retailer.retailer_shop_name,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 1 ,1,0)) AS feedback,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 2 ,1,0)) AS promise_order,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 3 ,1,0)) AS stock,
  SUM( IF( tbl_visit_info.activity_type = 6 ,1,0)) AS payment
  FROM tbl_visit_info,tbl_retailer
  where tbl_visit_info.retailer_id=tbl_retailer.retailer_id
  and tbl_visit_info.visitor_id='".$_GET["sr_id"]."' 
  and date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN 
  '".$_GET["start_date"]."' AND '".$_GET["end_date"]."'"
  group by visitor_id,retailer_id
```